# Network NIC on my MS Azure Server

Tags: networking, azure, nic, adapter

Quick question: I am installing Azure Stack POC and I had to disable all my network adapters (except one).
Once the installation will finish, I will be able to re activate my other adapters if needed?

Many thanks!
Stéphane

Comment: What is Azure Stack POC? Do you mean you're deploying an Azure virtual machine as a Proof of Concept? If so, why do you have multiple NIC's?

Comment: @joeqwerty Azure Stack is the new on premises version of Azure. It's currently in beta.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation, whilst not entirely clear,  states:

> The TP2 POC deployment supports exactly one NIC for networking. If you have multiple NICs, make sure that only one is enabled (and all others are disabled) before running the deployment script in the next section.

This statement reads to me that only 1 NIC is supported and that's it, not just for the deployment process.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Azure stack POC requires a single NIC.
We can read the [scope of Azure Stack POC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-stack/azure-stack-poc):
Azure stack POC networking scenarios are limited due to the single host/NIC requirement.
Here is a good article about the Azure stack architecture, please refer to the link below:
https://azurestack.eu/2016/10/dive-into-microsoft-azure-stack-architecture-part-2/